# Download from GAE a user's data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

glowscript.org is a Python-based GAE that stores user-written scripts in a datastore. How would I program in the Python server and/or JavaScript client a button that lets the user download to the user's Download directory one or more of the user's scripts? All I was able to find in my searching seemed to be oriented to me downloading the datastore from a command line, which seems unrelated to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I modified my csv example to download a python file (`.py`) instead

My Datastore model

```
class MetricsJob(ndb.Model):
    result = ndb.TextProperty(compressed=True) # the file body
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    # ... other fields
```

My Request handler

```
class MetricsDownload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, key):
        obj = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key).get()
        self.response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+obj.name+'.py'
        self.response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'Binary'
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(obj.result)
```

HTML code, all you need to do is initiate a HTTP GET:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/metrics/download/ahFkZXZ-cGF5LXRvbGxvLXdlYnIRCxIEVXNlchiAgICAgODECww/"></a>
```

The key to getting the browser to treat the HTTP GET as a file download was the response headers.

For your use case I would imagine you would need to set:

`self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'`

I'm not sure about the others

Comment: I've tried many permutations of your code without success. I've seen hints that maybe I have to do something to my app.yaml file, but I don't know what. Did you have to specify something in your yaml file to make this work?

Comment: I wouldn't think you have to do any `app.yaml` changes, maybe you saw someone talking about setting `mime_type` for `static_dir`. One thing i noticed I had that my answer didn't have was `target="_blank"` in my html. I made a couple other tweaks to my answer, I did a temporary change to my code and I'm able to download that csv as a python file now instead. Your webserver may be overwriting your headers after you set them. Are you also using webapp2?

Comment: After looking at lots of notes on the subject, I finally round a solution that works in my environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460202/google-app-engine-download-a-file-to-users-local-download-folder?noredirect=1#comment85928658_49460202